# Need HTML design of Tree view using PHP Array

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've one Array in PHP with limited data and static HTML view related to it which gives me tree view.

However; I need help to develop dynamic HTML code to view the same Data in Tree view.

**Static Array code as follow**

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';

$array = array(59336 => array(
array('parent_id' => 40503, 'child_id' => array()),
array('parent_id' => 20098, 'child_id' => array(array('parent_id' => 43849, 'child_id' => array(array('parent_id' => 43850, 'child_id' => array()), array('parent_id' => 43851, 'child_id' => array()))), array('parent_id' => 81542, 'child_id' => array()))),
array('parent_id' => 20099, 'child_id' => array(array('parent_id' => 43850, 'child_id' => array(array('parent_id' => 43851, 'child_id' => array()))), array('parent_id' => 81543, 'child_id' => array()))))
);

print_r($array);
?>
```

**Static HTML**

```
<ul id="tree-data" style="display:none">
    <li id="root">
          59336
          <ul>
                <li>
                      40503
                </li>
                <li>
                      20098
                      <ul>
                            <li>
                                  43849
                                  <ul>
                                        <li>
                                              43850
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                              43851
                                        </li>
                                  </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                  81542
                            </li>
                      </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                      20099
                      <ul>
                            <li>
                                  43850
                                  <ul>
                                        <li>
                                              43851
                                        </li>
                                  </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                  81543
                            </li>
                      </ul>
                </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Need Dynamic HTML code to print the data using Static Array instead of my static HTML code. Kindly help me.

Comment: You will have to use recursion

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879999/how-to-show-tree-view-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below function which help to generate array as per your requirement.

```
    <?php

    function nested2ul($data) {
        $result = array();

        if (sizeof($data) > 0) {
            $result[] = '<ul>';
            foreach ($data as $entry) {
                $result[] = sprintf(
                        '<li>%s %s</li>', $entry['parent_id'], nested2ul($entry['child_id'])
                );
            }
            $result[] = '</ul>';
        }

        return implode($result);
    }    
   ?>
```

The html code as below :

```
   <?php
     $html = '<ul id="tree-data" style="display:none"><li id="root">59336';
    $html .= nested2ul($array['59336']);
    $html .= '</li></ul>';
    echo $html;
    ?>
```